# Python Post request fails with 400/ConnectionResetError(10054) if params are lengthy

Tags: python, post, python-requests, query-string, python-3.7

I am relatively three months new to building tools with requests. In my institution, we have webapp and it calls 'POST' method to trigger an export query. I got the code right and it was working fine, except if the queried items are huge it fails throwing 400 Bad request or error out without completing the request as "requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))"

```
s = requests.Session()
var_list = ["var1", "var2", "var3", "var4"]
params_str = '%0D%0A'.join(var_list)
r = s.post(f'https://internaltools.org/export?variableids={params_str}')
print(r.status_code())
```

it works if len(var_list) =<300, fails if len(var_list) > 300

Is it the sever side or am i doing something wrong? Please help me out!

Comment: Why use `s.post` if you want to do GET request? (see the `?variableids=`). EDIT: internaltools.org is not available

Comment: Its a internal site accessed only via vpn. also the application is using POST method(sniffed in Chrome) even tried with GET

Comment: maybe you should take a look at the source code.

Comment: @Hanz Thanks, will try, but is there any global norms or limit to querystring, I even tried passing them via data/ Json payload it spawned 500

Comment: if the status_code is 500 you should look at the error logs in the site machine which can bring you more data to solve it, i recommend you to accept POST request rather than passing all of that long data through URL (you should avoid sending above 2,000 character to url)